# How to expand the dimension of an array and give it certain values in python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

I have a problem concerning the dimensionality of my input array.
I have a data set X of the shape (22221,3) but the library function I'm using requires: "Input shape: 3D tensor with shape: (nb_samples, timesteps, input_dim)"

So I know np.expand_dims(X, axis = 1). But the additional axis has the same values as one of my columns. But I want the additional axis to have the values of my timesteps array. So that the resulting shape would be something like: (22221, 22221, 3) and not (22221, 1, 3) like it's now.

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from initially creating an array of shape (22221,1,3) and then just only adding data to two of the dimensions?

Comment: I get a memory error when I'm trying to do it that way.